# check if control exists

Tags: html, asp-classic, vbscript

I have a password field that is on some pages and not on some pages. This is legacy code and it uses one include page for logic on both types of pages. I need to check if that control exists. I can't seem to find a way to check using vbscript.

some pages have

```
<label>Enter Password:</label> <input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd"/><br/>
```

some do not

Using ASP how do I check if it exists?

```
if (?????) then

end if
```

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "ASP" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: Are you trying to check in server-side code or client-side code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>Not real sure if you are running on the server or on the client. So I'll take a stab its on the client. This might work for you.</strike>

```
if ( TypeName(document.getElementById("pwd")) ) <> "Nothing" then
    MsgBox("found!")
else 
    MsgBox("not found!")
end if
```

Update:

Since this is server side, and vbscript is pretty long in the tooth, I dimly remember this working for me:

```
if isEmpty(Request.Form("pwd")) then
   //-- not there... 
else
   //-- its there ....
end if
```

Comment: returns Object required: 'document'

Comment: Ah my apologies. I didn't see your comment that this was server side coding when I posted my answer.

Comment: @skyburner:  Consider deleting or using <strike>old stuff</strike> on the earlier stuff in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Server-side ASP:

```
if request("pwd") <> "" then

end if
```

Comment: returns Object variable not set